# How do I force windows authentication with local asp.net development server?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, authentication

I'm developing an ASP.NET application which needs Windows Authentication.  I have the web.config set up to deny anonymous users and use Windows mode for authentication, but my local development version still lets me pass right through to the site.  In order to test different user set-ups, I need to force authorization so I can change users.

How do I set up my system (config files, VS2005 settings, IIS, etc?) to force the authorization window to popup on the site when I'm running on local asp.net development server?  In other words, how do I get the authentication popup when running the site in Debug mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need to configure IIS and have your application point to IIS instead of the local web server

> To configure Windows authentication
>
> 1. Start Internet Information Services (IIS).
> 2. Right-click your application's virtual directory, and then click Properties.
> 3. Click the Directory Security tab.
> 4. Under Anonymous access and authentication control, click Edit.
> 5. Make sure the Anonymous access check box is not selected and that Integrated Windows > authentication is the only selected check box.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998358.aspx

To configure your application to point to IIS

1. Right click on your web project, and then click Properties
2. Click the Web tab
3. Click the "Use Local IIS Web Server" radio button